# How to replace a sequence in vector

Tags: c++, c++11

Let's assume that I have the following vector:

```
std::vector<int> data{0,1,2,3,4};
```

I would like to replace the sequence {1,2,3} with a single number. I have found an example with std::replace but there a single number is replaced with other single number. How to replace a sequence in vector ?

Comment: Remove two of three values. Then replace the existing one.

Answer (score 1):

We can do this using [`std::vector::erase(const_iterator first, const_iterator last)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) as follows.
The following function replace the value of `org[start]` to `val` and then erases the elements in the range `[start+1, end]`:

[**DEMO**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/tTNaArsng1ZMJbQ3)

```
template<class T>
std::vector<T> replace(
    const std::vector<T>& org, 
    std::size_t start, 
    std::size_t end, 
    const T& val)
{
    assert(start <= end);
    assert(end < org.size());

    auto vec(org);
    auto it_s = vec.begin() + start;
    *it_s = val;

    vec.erase(it_s + 1, vec.begin() + end + 1);

    return vec;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've generalized your question into any STL container by using iterator pairs instead of vectors for input. The algorithm has 3 steps:

1. Find sequence via [std::search](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search). Return `last` if it is not found
2. Replace first sequence item with new value
3. Remove remaining items with [std::remove_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove)

As iterators cannot really erase items from container, `data.erase(newEnd, data.end());` call is needed to shrink vector.

Algorithm should be quite stable and work even for 1-element vectors.
Function can be declared `constexpr` since C++14.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <class ForwardIt1, class ForwardIt2, class Value>
constexpr ForwardIt1 replaceSequenceWithValue(ForwardIt1 first, ForwardIt1 last, 
                                              ForwardIt2 s_first, ForwardIt2 s_last,
                                              Value &&value) {
  auto seq_start = std::search(first, last, s_first, s_last);
  if (seq_start == last)
    return last; // return last if no seq was found

  *seq_start = std::forward<Value>(value);

  auto itemsToBeRemoved = std::distance(s_first, s_last) - 1;

  // return new end
  if (itemsToBeRemoved > 0)
    return std::remove_if(std::next(seq_start), last,
                          [&itemsToBeRemoved](const auto &) { return itemsToBeRemoved-- > 0; });
  return last;
}


int main() {
  std::vector<int> data{0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
  std::vector<int> seq{1, 2, 3};
  auto newEnd = replaceSequenceWithValue(data.begin(), data.end(), seq.begin(), seq.end(), 5);
  data.erase(newEnd, data.end());
  for (auto d : data) {
    std::cout << d << '\n';
  }
}
```

If you don't need such generalization you can wrap it into function with simpler signature:

```
template <class Value>
constexpr void replaceSequenceWithValue(std::vector<Value> &data, const std::vector<Value> &sequence, Value &&value) {
  auto newEnd = replaceSequenceWithValue(data.begin(), data.end(), sequence.begin(),
                                         sequence.end(), std::forward<Value>(value));
  data.erase(newEnd, data.end());
}
```

And use like:

```
int main() {
  std::vector<int> data{0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
  replaceSequenceWithValue(data, {1, 2, 3}, 5);
  for (auto d : data) {
    std::cout << d << '\n';
  }
}
```

Comment: I am not convinced about `std::remove_if` here, but I could not come up with anything better. `std::rotate` may work, but it would move items just to be discarded into end of `data` vector. `std::shift_left` from C++20 would be perfect to use here.

Answer (score 0):

First :
[vector::erase](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/)

```
// erasing from vector
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main ()
{
std::vector<int> myvector;

// set some values (from 1 to 10)
for (int i=1; i<=10; i++) myvector.push_back(i);

// erase the 6th element
myvector.erase (myvector.begin()+5);

// erase the first 3 elements:
myvector.erase (myvector.begin(),myvector.begin()+3);

std::cout << "myvector contains:";
for (unsigned i=0; i<myvector.size(); ++i)
std::cout << ' ' << myvector[i];
std::cout << '\n';

return 0;
}
```

Output:
myvector contains: 4 5 7 8 9 10

Then :
[vector::insert](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/)

```
// inserting into a vector
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main ()
{
std::vector<int> myvector (3,100);
std::vector<int>::iterator it;

it = myvector.begin();
it = myvector.insert ( it , 200 );

myvector.insert (it,2,300);

// "it" no longer valid, get a new one:
it = myvector.begin();

std::vector<int> anothervector (2,400);
myvector.insert (it+2,anothervector.begin(),anothervector.end());

int myarray [] = { 501,502,503 };
myvector.insert (myvector.begin(), myarray, myarray+3);

std::cout << "myvector contains:";
for (it=myvector.begin(); it<myvector.end(); it++)
std::cout << ' ' << *it;
std::cout << '\n';

return 0;
}
```

Output:
myvector contains: 501 502 503 300 300 400 400 200 100 100 100

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can write a custom function, like this:

```
    vector<int> replace_sequence(const vector<int> in,int start,int end,int replace)
    {
        vector<int> res;
        //check the index value
        if(start<0 || end > in.size() || start > end){
            return res;
        }
        int distance = end -start;
        //construct the result
        for(int i=0;i<in.size();i++){
            if(i==start){
                res.push_back(replace);
                i+=distance;
            }else{
                res.push_back(in[i]);
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bool erase_replace_seq (vector <int>& data, int start, int end, int replace)
{
    bool result = false;
if ((start<data.size () && start>=0)  && (end < data.size () && end >=0 && end >= start))
    {
        auto iter = data.erase (data.begin () + start, data.begin () + end);
        data.insert (iter, replace);
        result = true;
    }

    return result;
}
```